PROBLEMA INSTALANDO LIBRERIAS GOLANG
estoy empezando a usar go y hasta ahora no habia tenido problemas con las librerias...pero ahora no puedo instalar ninguna.
Esto es lo que me lanza
go: github.com/webview/webview_go@v0.0.0-20240831120633-6173450d4dd6: verifying module: github.com/webview/webview_go@v0.0.0-20240831120633-6173450d4dd6: initializing sumdb.Client: reading tree note: malformed note
note:
Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Solucion:
Corre go clean -modcache y luego intenta nuevamente instalar la librería.
go clean -modcache


No me funcionó, Sigue dándome el mismo error :( Incluso ya desinstale e instale de nuevo golang
